# Dúvida em relação a modelagem

Tags: banco-de-dados

Boa noite, tenho que fazer um banco de dados para uma simples loja de vendas online, mas estou num dilema de quais tabelas criar e gostaria de opinião de vocês.
No caso, eu criei as tabelas:

- Cliente
- Produtos
- Compra

No caso,a compra iria unir as duas, com id do cliente e do produto, além de outros campos.
Estou certo ou poderia fazer de maneira diferente?

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa fazer um relacionamento Many to Many em produtos e clientes, esse relacionamento resulta em uma tabela produto_cliente, com uma chave estrangeira de produtos e clientes. A necessidade disso é que vários clientes podem ter comprado um mesmo produto, consequentemente o contrário, um único produto está relacionado a vários usuários (isso é útil caso você precise saber o histórico de compras de um cliente, ou de um produto)

A tabela compras eu mudaria para pedidos, guardando o id do cliente e o id do endereço de entrega (caso seu sistema suporte vários endereços de um mesmo cliente), a chave primária seria o ID de compra, nessa tabela você guarda outras coisas essenciais como valor total, tipo de entrega, data de compra, essas informações.

Por fim outra tabela de nome compras_produto, onde eu guardo por meio de chave estrangeira de pedidos, e produto suas respectivas chaves primárias, nessa tabela incluo quantidade, preço unitário e data, talvez outras informações caso necessário.

Por desconhecer totalmente o domínio da sua aplicação, alguns relacionamentos One to Many e One to One são necessários, mas trocando em miúdos, essa é uma das alternativas que eu adotaria, um banco de dados bem modelado contribui fortemente com o desempenho de sua aplicação, já que um dos processos mais custosos é justamente a realização de consultas.

Comment: Tipo, quando o usuário entra na página ele vê os produtos e seleciona os que ele deseja, indo para o carrinho, com isso ele seleciona a quantidade,insere estado/cidade etc. Na hora de finalizar o pedido ele seleciona se quer logar ou criar um cadastro. Depois de logado ele finaliza o pedido e vai para outra página que mostra os pedidos dele.

Comment: Eu tinha feito como vc disse dos relacionamentos, mas eu tava apanhando muito com as tabelas e nao estava sabendo como inserir e como fazer os joins, entao queria optar por essa escolha de um banco simples.

Comment: Seu banco de dados pode ate ser simples, porem você não vai conseguir fugir dos relacionamentos ou de um join monstruoso para juntar todos os dados que você precisa, por isso a importância dos relacionamentos M2M, O2O e O2M. É preciso acima de tudo criar um balanço, não complexo de mais e nem simples de mais. Como diz o ditado, o barato sai caro.

Comment: Pedidos tambem nao teria relacionamento n-n com cliente?

Comment: Pedidos e clientes e One to Many, um cliente pode ter vários pedidos, mas um pedido está relacionado apenas a um cliente. Caso tenha dúvidas sobre relacionamentos abra outra pergunta.